# Get data from the current item task using InfoPath

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

I have been struggling to find a solution for it but I hope you can help me out.
I have a Sharepoint list with the following fields:

```
ID (generated automatically) 
PLANT (dropdown with the data: LMS, LMA and SAN)
FIELD1
FIELD2
FIELD3 ... etc
```

The users add a new item into this list and then start a workflow. So far so good.
The data on this list will be something like this:

```
1, LMS
2, LMA
3, LMS
4, LMA
5, LMA
```

The problem is that I want to get the "Plant" field data from this specific item task and display it on InfoPath form. What is happening when I try to use the Secondary Data its showing all "Plant" from **all items** on the list:

[image]

It was supposed to show only one result because I want it from the **current item list.**

Answer (score 0):

You can add a filter to get the Plant field data. Here is a demo for your reference：

[image]

The result as below:

[image]

Comment: It didn't work as expected. Did you try to create other items on your list? Question: when you are comparison ID = ID, the first ID is from the Secondary list and the other is from your Main, right?

Comment: Hi, I was able to figure out a way to do it. I realized the InfoPath has a different ID for each form, so what I have done was creating a new field called ID FORM in Sharepoint List, so on the task behavior in the workflow, I updated the field ID  FORM with the INFOPATH ID. So I was able to compare the ID FORM field with the ID from INFOPATH and the results were only one.